# Как правильно реализовать удаление аккаунта? (База данных)

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем! Залез в такие дебри, что не могу разобраться. Разрабатывается ресурс, где зарегистрированные пользователи оставляют комментарии. В каждой записи таблицы (comments)  содержится комментарий и id пользователя. При отображении комментария, через этот id определяется и выводится имя пользователя. Как быть, если пользователь решил удалить свой аккаунт?

По идее я должен удалить его профиль из БД. При этом его id больше не существуют, а значит и не отобразится имя в комментарии. Я нашел только один выход - сохранять в таблице не его id, а само имя. Тогда даже при удалении аккаунта, имя-то всегда будет отображаться. Вообще, как все это реализуется в современных веб-приложениях? Может быть, я вообще все неправильно делаю?

Comment: Пользователя можно реально и не удалять из базы, а просто пометить, что он удален (более неактивен).

Comment: @avp, об этом я тоже подумал, но ведь БД будет тогда иметь в конце-концов тонные ненужного мусора!

Comment: Ну, удалите те данные, что явно не нужны, а те на которые есть ссылки из активных - оставьте.

Comment: Аккаунты удалять будут пару раз на сотни мертвяков. Посмотрите на список участников на ХК. Там куча мертвых аккаунтов не потому что аккаунт удалить нельзя, а потому что бросают. Надежда на то, что вам удастся не хранить тонны мусора, очень слабая.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, разве это проблема? )) Например, я могу жестоко удалять аккаунты, если пользователя не было на сайте более года и т.д. (как это в свое время делал mail.ru). Просто, используя user_name вместо  user_id, я действительно решаю кучу проблем.

Comment: @Deus проблема если и есть, то она ваша, естественно. насколько для вас не важен человек, который прошел регистрацию со всеми капчами и проч, а он может он читает вас каждый день, но не пишет комментарии, а вы его раз и удаляете, - ваше решение. Удаляйте тогда со всеми его следами. Будет девственный сервер.  
"Тонны ненужного мусора" будут у вас в комментариях. По большому счету, человек, оставивший хотя бы один комментарий, уже намусорил своим ником и даже если вы его удалите, все равно его данные останутся. А флудеры забьют вам таблицу комментариев своими никами гораздо сильнее.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в споре рождается истина. Уже все подправил - аккаунт из таблицы не удаляется, просто status становиться равным "0". Ресурс все-таки будет связан с политикой, вдруг придется отыскать человека (чтобы,например, расстрелять :) ).

Во всех таблицах есть только поле user_id. 

Еще одна проблема - при использовании JOIN не работает COUNT. Не знаю пока, что и делать.

Comment: @Deus count работает, вы что-то не так делаете )

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ага, работает! Я просто что-то не так делал. )))

Comment: @Deus, а почему Вас так волнует этот мусор?

Совершенно реально можно взять сетевой RAID на 4TB (2 HDD) баксов за 500 (смешные деньги).

Просто прикиньте, сколько времени понадобиться колотить по клавишам вашей армии пользователей, чтобы заполнить этот объем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты:

- Как уже подсказал [avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp), можно просто выставить пользователям флажок, активен или нет
- Сохранять имя пользователя в поле таблицы комментариев (такая денормализация БД допустима при высоких нагрузках и обязательности сохранения данных [да и если кроме этого в выводе комментария от пользователей больше ничего не нужно, это избавит вас от JOINa с таблицей пользователей])
- (Если таблицы в InnoDB) Поставить внешнему ключу **user_id** ON DELETE SET NULL, тогда утеряется логин автора комментария, но его можно заменить чем-то вроде "инкогнито"

Comment: @dekameron, спасибо. Ваш второй пункт ответа полностью подтвердил мои догадки!

Comment: Можно ещё ничего не брать от старого пользователя, а просто подставлять текст «DELETED». Какая разница, кто оставил этот комментарий, если пользователя уже нет?

Comment: @orkaan, это круто. Но на нормальных форумах, порталах все равно вписываются имена в комментариях 5-летней давности! Я уже дважды поменял структуру БД! Так какой-же оптимальный вариант?

Comment: @Deus, я считаю, именно вам необходимо принять это решение, т.к. всё зависит от проекта и от ценности объектов в таблицах БД. Мне, например, подойдёт вариант, когда при удалении пользователя, *удаляются и все записи в других таблицах*, где пользователь представлен как FK; кому-то ещё достаточно будет просто *пометить пользователя как удалённого* (очень хороший вариант — статусы); а вам *нужно имя и нужно содержимое* комментария или поста.
И здесь именно вы должны решить, что и как показывать и при каких условиях удалять!